# trigger causing #1054 - Unknown column 'x' in 'where clause'

Tags: mysql, triggers, mysql-error-1054

My trigger looks like this:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `trigger_name`;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `trigger_name` 
AFTER UPDATE ON `table1`
 FOR EACH ROW UPDATE `table2` SET `modified` = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE `id` = `NEW.id`
//
DELIMITER ;
```

This crashes with the above error (#1054) if a do this:

```
UPDATE table1 SET owner = NULL WHERE id = 82
```

---

Found the solution! The problem is the back-quotes/backticks (`). If I rewrite the trigger like

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trigger_name;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name
AFTER UPDATE ON table1
 FOR EACH ROW UPDATE table2 SET modified = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE id = NEW.id
//
DELIMITER ;
```

Everything works fine! :-) I supose the lesson is never use back-quotes/backticks (`) unless strictly nessesary.

Answer (score 1):

> *The problem is the back-quotes/backticks (`)*

The problem is not in the backpacks, but rather in the fact that you used them improperly

```
...WHERE `id` = `NEW.id`
                ^      ^
```

By writing it in this way you're telling MySQL that you want to update all rows in the table which have the same value in *two* columns `id` and `NEW.id`. Yes you can have a column with such a name if you want to. Here is a **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4069ef/1)** demo.

1. a `NEW` keyword shouldn't be backticked
2. you need to backtick object identifiers **only** (`id` in your case) when you use dot notation (`<table>.<column>`).

Written properly it should've been looked like this instead

```
...WHERE `id` = NEW.`id`
                    ^  ^
```

That being said if you're not using restricted characters or reserved words in database object identifiers there is no need to use backtiks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the back-quotes/backticks (`). See the edit of the original question